# Implementing skip/take pagination via pageIndex/pageSize pagination when skip is not divisible by take

Tags: c#, pagination, ienumerable

Suppose that I have some magically paginated black box class that retrieves data by using `pageIndex` and `pageSize` as follows:

```
public class PaginatedList<T>
{
    // ...

    // Chops up the internally stored list into pages of size "pageSize",
    // then returns the page stored at index "pageIndex".
    public IEnumerable<T> Get(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        // Magic black box code goes here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now suppose that I have a driver class that wants to use this `PaginatedList` class, but wants to achieve pagination by using `skip` and `take` parameters. Certainly, if the offset that I want to `skip` by happens to be divisible by the amount that I want to `take`, then I can achieve this by doing something like the following:

```
public class MyDriver
{
    // Bypass the first "skip" elements and return the next "take" elements.
    static IEnumerable<T> OffsetGet(PaginatedList<T> myList, int skip, int take)
    {
        // ASSERT: skip % take == 0 is true.
        return myList.Get(skip/take, take);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...

        // From some dataSource, store some strings in a fancy PaginatedList.
        var myList = new PaginatedList<string>(dataSource);

        // Skip the first 20 strings and take the next 5 strings.
        var myData = OffsetGet(myList, 20, 5);

        // ...
    }
}
```

But how else can I implement `OffsetGet(myList, skip, take)` efficiently (that is, without making more than one `Get(pageIndex, pageSize)` call) for the case where the offset that I want to `skip` by is **not** divisible by the amount that I want to `take`?

Apologies if this question has already been answered somewhere or if the above code is too vague; this is my first question on StackOverflow, so please be gentle. =]

Comment: Nice question. I wondered whether it was just a matter of finding the GCD, but it's not that simple... How much do you care about only fetching the minimum amount of data?

Comment: Also, is the pageIndex zero-based or 1-based?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I don't care too much if we end up fetching a few extra records then pruning the result; the main bottleneck is the `Get` call, which shouldn't be called more than once.

Comment: @astander Hmm, I'm not sure actually. I suspect that it has to be zero-based, given that `OffsetGet(myList, 20, 5)` should be equivalent to `Get(4, 5)`. I might have some off-by-one errors though. Feel free to change the indexing to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: there are significant issues with this answer (which is accepted so can't be deleted) - e.g. a skip of 28 with a take of 5. I don't have time to fix this, unfortunately.

---

This partly depends on how much you want to balance code complexity vs data fetching efficiency.

You could *always* succeed by fetching twice as much data as you need:

```
int virtualTake = take * 2;
int virtualSkip = skip / virtualTake;
var bigList = Get(myList, virtualSkip, virtualTake);
int offset = virtualSkip % take;
var pruned = bigList.Skip(offset).Take(take);
```

However, that will fetch more data than you need to in many cases. You could *at least* optimize for the case where `skip` is already a multiple of `take`, but there are other cases where you could improve.

For example, if you want to skip 23 and take 5, the above will *effectively* skip 20 and take 10, then prune... but you *could* skip 21 and take 7 instead. Code based on the suggestion by astander in comments below:

```
int newTake = take;
while ((skip % newTake) + take > newTake)
{
     newTake++;
}
var bigList = Get(myList, skip / newTake, newTake);
int offset = skip % newTake;
var pruned = bigList.Skip(offset).Take(take);
```

Comment: how about something like 
`int newTake = take;
while ((skip / newTake + 1) * newTake < (skip + take)) newTake++;
int newSkip = (skip / newTake) * newTake;`

Comment: I tested this for a couple of windows and it seems to work as expected to return the minimal window size to overlap the `take` size

Comment: @astander: Yes, that may well do it. For very large values of `take`, it may be less efficient than over-fetching - but that really depends on things we don't know about. Mind if I add that code into my answer? (Or you could create your own answer, certainly...)

Comment: please go ahead and add it to the answer.

Comment: @astander: Done. I *think* I've adapted it appropriately :)

Comment: This solution is brilliant. Thanks to both of you guys!

Comment: Feeling weird cpmmenting on something that is 8 years old, but does this solution even work ? For the first solution even if you replace virtualSkip with skip in lines 3 and 4 the aproach seems wrong as if you change the example to skip 28 take 5, these cannot be fit into a single take 10 page request. For the second solution the loop as is seems to be infinite for most inputs.

Comment: @Daniel: I'll have another look when I'm back from holiday.

Comment: @Daniel: Had a look now, and you're absolutely right. I believe it's fixable, but it would take more energy than I've got available to fix it right now :(

Comment: @JonSkeet: The second approach is fixable - you can just change the while condition to while ((skip % newTake) + take > newTake) with worst case newTake=2*take -1 for cases like skip 99 take 100. For my particular case I have a max limit of 100 for pages and this combined with the bonus complexity makes a solution with multiple page requests prefereble in most cases.

Comment: @Daniel: Okay, I've edited it - but to be honest I haven't validated it thoroughly. And yes, I can easily imagine that in many cases making two requests is a better bet.

Answer (score -1):

You ca directly use Skip and Take methods of LINQ

```
return mylist.Skip(skip).Take(take).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. The OP only has access to the `Get` method, and wants to work out what arguments to pass.